# grails create-plugin doesn't work

Tags: grails

when i run this command
`grails create-plugin example`

i am getting this error:

```
| Error Command not found create-plugin
Did you mean: package-plugin or create-script or create-interceptor?
```

| Grails Version: 3.1.8
| Groovy Version: 2.4.6
| JVM Version: 1.7.0_101

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this when I try to create a plugin inside an existing plugin.

If you are trying to create a second plugin, you need to run `create-plugin` in a different directory that isn't an existing Grails plugin or application.